# CSS float inside the list avoid unwanted padding

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

In my list element I want to place the control buttons aside, from the left of the list item text. In order to do that I use a property `float: left;`, it does the job, but when there are more than one line in a list, every new line has a padding of a size of the previous floating block:

[image]

The list is based on Vue.js & Bootstrap.
My CSS/HTML code:

```html
<ul class="items">
   <transition-group name="item">
      <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" mode="out-in">
         <span>
            {{item.properties.NAME}}
         </span>
         <span style="float: left;">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" @click="edit_item(item)"><span class="fa fa-wrench"></span>Update</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" @click="confirm_delete_item(item)"><span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span>Delete</a>
         </span>
      </li>
   </transition-group>
</ul>
```

How to display buttons inside the list on the right/left side of the list just one under the other?

The final result should be something like that:

- Item #1_____________________________________Update___Delete
- Item #2_____________________________________Update___Delete

Comment: In Bootstrap 4, a simple job like this can be done without any css hacking. `float: left;` is css hacking in my book because Bootstrap 4 allows getting done almost everything using native classes alone. But I'd need to see the complete HTML output snippet to be able to tell which Bootstrap class you need in that case.

Comment: One consequence of unnecessary css hacks in Bootstrap 4 is that css hacks require even more css hacks to fix the problems created by the original css hacks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue should be solved by resetting or clearing the float that you’ve created. As you’re using bootstrap you can simply add the class `clearfix` to your `li` element that you have added float to. This will add a pseudo after element which will reset the flat after the element.

The final code snippet:

```
<ul class="items">
   <transition-group name="item">
      <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" mode="out-in" style="padding-bottom:10px;" clearfix>
         {{item.properties.NAME}}
         <span style="float: left;">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" @click="edit_item(item)"><span class="fa fa-wrench"></span>עדכן</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" @click="confirm_delete_item(item)"><span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span>מחק</a>
         </span>
      </li>
   </transition-group>
</ul>
```

Comment: Alternatively, it's possible to use `<span style="float: left; clear:left;">` instead of `clearfix`.

Answer (score 1):

Try style="clear:left;".  If that doesn't work, you would actually do the float or the clear left on the  'li' element, not on the span containing the buttons. This way each 'li' containing the buttons will contain the buttons themselves.

Try something to this affect below. Since there is not a JS Fiddle, editing code for what your needs are harder to edit.

```
<ul class="items">
<transition-group name="item">
  <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" mode="out-in" style="float:left; clear:left; width:100%; display:block">
     <span>
        {{item.properties.NAME}}
     </span>
     <span>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" @click="edit_item(item)">
  <span class="fa fa-wrench"></span>Update</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" @click="confirm_delete_item(item)"><span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span>Delete</a>
     </span>
  </li>
</transition-group>
</ul>
```

Kind of like this. Quick and dirty. Except on the elements, instead of inline styling, highly recommend CSS.

https://jsfiddle.net/y1x53zx2/1/

Comment: Along those same lines, if bootstrap is in use (depending on which version)  simple class of `clearfix` on the `li` element would provide the structuring to resolve the float issue.

Comment: @ClosDesign, `float:left; clear:left` on a `li` level didn't help to solve the issue, while `clearfix` on `li` and `float:left;` on a `span` level works great. Or it's possible to use `clear:left` on a `li` level and `float:left;` on a `span` level as well.